# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" in spring-beans4.3.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, hibernate-validator

After upgrading from spring-boot 1.4.2.RELEASE to 1.5.1.RELEASE (which comes with the new spring-beans4.3.6.Release) my tests started to fail with the following error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

In my code i have custom annotation (riding on hibrenate-validator5.4.0.Final) which is defined for ElementType.TYPE_USE and ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER in order to be able to iterate over sets.

```
Set<@ElementSize(min = MIN_LENGTH, max = MAX_ID_LENGTH) String> ids
```

My test simply sends a set with an empty value inside to fail on range validation:

```
Set<String> ids = new HashSet<>();
ids.add("");
```

Before the upgrade i used to get MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException and analyze the exception but now i fail on the above error.

I've done some digging in Spring-beans code and i saw the following in `AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java`

```
else if (value instanceof Set) {
// Apply index to Iterator in case of a Set.    
Set<Object> set = (Set<Object>) value;
int index = **Integer.parseInt(key);**
if (index < 0 || index >= set.size()) {
    throw new InvalidPropertyException(getRootClass(),
              this.nestedPath + propertyName,
            "Cannot get element with index " + index + " 
             from Set of size " + set.size() + ", accessed 
             using property path '" + propertyName + "'");
}
```

Debugging the code shows that "key" holds the empty value "" from the set 
and by trying to parse it to Integer it fails.

Is it a bug in spring or an improvement in which i somehow need to modify my code to?

> Temporary solution:

After some more investigation it seems if we use a lower version of hibernate-validator to 5.2.4.Final all is working and we can upgrade spring-boot to 1.5.1.

Comment: Please pay more attention to formatting when posting. Use the preview to check that the post looks appropriate *before* you hit post. I've edited your question to be much more readable this time, but please do this yourself in future.